# How to get lastest date group by employee of a column but without another column

Tags: sql

I'm working a query in SQL 2005.
I'm trying to **get the latest date for a number column.** The trick is there is another column (rate) that use the column date and I fetch the wrong column in the end.

An example will better explain my question.

This is my SQL table EmployeeRates:

```
----------------------------------
FkEmployee | Date | Rate | Number |
----------------------------------
1           2000   15     1.5
1           2001   16     1.5
1           2002   16     1.6

2           2000   12     1.5     
2           2001   14     1.6
2           2002   15     1.6
```

So if I fetch the latest date, currently I have :

- FkEmployee #1 = 2002 (which is correct because it's the latest date for the number column.)
- FkEmployee #2 = 2002 (which is not what I want, because that year it was the rate that changed and there is a duplicate number) What I want is **2001**.

The code I have right now (2015-08-10 14:15)

```
SELECT t1.FkEmployee, t1.Date
FROM EmployeeRates t1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT FkEmployee, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
        FROM EmployeeRates
        GROUP BY FkEmployee
    )
    t2 ON t1.FkEmploye = t2.FkEmploye 
    AND t1.DateTaux = t2.MaxDate
ORDER BY t1.FkEmploye
```

Thanks for anybody that can help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. First find `MIN` date by Employee, Number, then get the `MAX` of that. This will ensure you are getting the earliest date per number, but latest date per employee:

```
SELECT t1.FkEmployee, t1.Date
FROM EmployeeRates t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT FkEmployee,MAX(MinDate) AS MaxDate from
        (SELECT FkEmployee, MIN(Date) AS MinDate
        FROM EmployeeRates
        GROUP BY FkEmployee,Number) a
     GROUP BY Fkemployee
    )
    t2 ON t1.FkEmployee = t2.FkEmployee 
    AND t1.DateTaux = t2.MaxDate
ORDER BY t1.FkEmployee
```

Comment: Wow! It really works =) There is just a minor error in your sample code: it's MAX(MinDate), because when I tried MAX(Date) it says that 'Invalid column name'.

I will study it more now that it's working (not sure to understand the min part).

Thanks you very much for your quick respond!